# Can't scp to AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I can ssh to my linux instance using the following:

```
ssh -i dj_mongo.pem -v ec2-user@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

But whenever I am trying to copy file from the local computer to server, I am getting the following errors:

```
 scp -i dj_mongo.pem ck.pem  root@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/
Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user.

 scp -i dj_mongo.pem ck.pem  ec2-user@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Both dj_mongo-pem and ck.pem has permissions 600.

Output from terminal is copied below:

```
 Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com [xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file dj_mongo.pem type -1
debug1: identity file dj_mongo.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/sadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/sadmin/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: dj_mongo.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

How can I proceed with that?
Please help.

EDITED
Now I can't ssh anymore. I am using the same key as yesterday.

Comment: Do you have write-right to the remote system root folder as ec2-user?

Comment: I am getting this no matter where I am trying to copy the file.
For example 
sadmin$ scp -i dj_mongo.pem ck.pem  ec2-user@ec2-54-243-218-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user

ec2-user is owned by ec2-user and has 777 permissions

Comment: Also I copied some files there before...but I don't remember how I did it.

Comment: I think that problem lies in authentication. Have you read [this](http://superuser.com/a/223865)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find out what was a reason of my problem.
I ended it up by creating new Linux Instance, and attaching the EBS of my old instance that stopped responding to it.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical verbose scp output

```
debug1: Trying private key: dj_mongo.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to your.server.com ([i.p.v.4]:22).
```

In your output, after reading the private PEM key, it is skipping it.

Few obvious things -

1. Was the server launched with a same key corresponding to dj_mongo.pem?
2. Are you connecting to the same server?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but many flavors of linux block SSH/SCP access via root user. Especially if you're using Amazon AMI, they set up a root user known as ec2-user, which you should have already uploaded your pem key to, so you should be all set on logging in as this user.